# Query doesn't complete if filter range used is smaller

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following works quite well:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table1 T1 WHERE T1.StaffId IN (select Id From Staff WHERE DeptId=5)
    AND T1.LastUpdatedOn>'2013-07-01'
```

There are only 38 records returned from the above query.  If I have `T1.LastUpdatedOn>'2013-07-02'`, the number of rows returned should be equal to or smaller than 38.

The odd thing is that it works fine for dates up to `2013-07-07`.  The moment I use a date of `2013-07-08` or later, the query never run to completion.

What could be wrong?

---

Adding more info:

Actual SQL Profile output, only column names changed:

```
select * from fish F where F.StaffId in 
(select Id from view_Staff where Dept='xxx' and Site='yyy')
and F.LastUpdatedOn>'2013-07-01'
```

The above took CPU: 749, Reads: 261243, Writes: 528, and Duration: 747.

If I simply changed the date to '2013-07-08' the query didn't complete.  When I killed it, it already consumed CPU: 88453, Reads: 7295813, Writes: 523 and Duration: 88464.

What could the increased Reads mean, when the data to be returned is actually less?

Comment: There really shouldn't be any reason for it to act strange when you use that particular date. Have you checked the consistency of your data? Can you post the exact query you run when it never completes.

Comment: @emagana: What do you mean by consistency?  There are a total of 38 records with LastUpdatedOn >'2013-07-01'.  So the original query already manaaged to get every row.  Any date later than Jul 1 should just return a subset of the same data right?

Comment: @OldGeezer does your code execute or not? or the value you need is wrong?

Comment: @Bew Please see new info I added.  Thanks.

Comment: I've had an instance at work before where the root cause ended up being too many indexes, or better to say badly designed indexes. how are your indexes looking?

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to check the query plan.